# Finding Last "Known" Location of a GPS Connected Device

Tags: gps

Is there a way to find last "known" location of a gps connected device through its GPS ID? A website or any services?

Answer (score 0):

GPS devices are *passive*, so nobody is tracking any use of GPS signals - there is no interaction between the GPS device and the satellites.

Therefore, nobody could know where they were last used.

Some devices have that feature explicitly built in through other means, for example, iPhones can be set to track their location under their apple-ID. They send this data through LTE or wireless connections to Apple, though, as there is no way to communicate back to the GPS satellite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've lost my DJI Phantom and I could I may find it in that way but it seems that's not possible